# jQuery Execute Old Variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code.

```
function changepriceedu() {
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("select#calc_shipping_state").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.single-product-top.row ins').replaceWith('<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.</span>' + totalshippingcost + '</span></ins>');
    jQuery('div#boton_info ins').replaceWith('<ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">S/.</span>' + totalshippingcost + '</span></ins>');
  });

});
}
```

I put a variable in another php file like this.

```
echo "<script>";
echo "var totalshippingcost = $totalshippingcost;";
echo "</script>";
```

But when calling the variable I get an old and not new value with the ".change" function, what would be the problem?